# One Server, one domain Many Reverse DNS

Tags: reverse

I have a dedicated server to host one domain. I have lots of ips. Is it possible theese ips reverse dns ?

Example :

```
On One Server, and domain
127.0.0.1  Reverse DNS : a1.xyz.com
127.0.0.2  Reverse DNS : a2.xyz.com
127.0.0.3  Reverse DNS : a3.xyz.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDNS you can have multiple reverse DNS IP address with different hostnames. "While most rDNS entries only have one PTR record, DNS does not restrict the number.". It is said not recommended since it depends on programs to really read all replies. there is a discussion in talks on the wiki page about that subject http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Reverse_DNS_lookup "Multiple records".
I might be that in future, program should adapt to this since it is very usual to have many virtual hosts / web servers on the same host.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set a reverse DNS name **per IP address**. If you have multiple IPs then you can set multiple reverse DNS names.